# Function creates buttons but they can't trigger other functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, kivy, kivy-language

I'm Trying to build a dynamic layout in Kivy, my function generates buttons but they are not able to trigger any other function that would be responsible for the creation of labels:

```
def candidate_builder(self):
    file = open('GSUCandidates.txt', 'r')
    for names in file:
        names = names.rstrip()
        if 'President' in names:
            cbl_layout = self.ids['cs_grid']
            cn_label = Label(bold=True, text=names)
            cn_button = Button(id='pr', bold=True, text='Vote')
            cn_button.on_release = show()
            cbl_layout.add_widget(cn_label)
            cbl_layout.add_widget(cn_button)
            cbl_layout.height = cbl_layout.height + 250

            def show():
                vp_label = Label(bold=True, text=names)
                cpl_layout = self.ids['csp_grid']
                cpl_layout.add_widget(vp_label)
```

Comment: `cn_button.on_release = show()` calls "show" and assigns the return value to the property. You want to assign the function without calling so omit the parentheses.

Comment: it still returns the following error TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
cn_button = Button(id='pr', bold=True, text='Vote', on_release=show)
...
def show(*args):
```

Or in case you want to send some variables to your method to should use lambda:

```
cn_button = Button(id='pr', bold=True, text='Vote', on_release=lambda event: show()) # <- here you should have parentheses, where you can put anything you want
...
def show():
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `show` in quotes (that makes it a string, not a function reference). I think you need to to use

```
cn_button.on_release = show
```

and I think it needs to appear after the `def show()`. Also, the Button instance will be passed to the `show()` method, so you need to define it as:

```
def show(butt_instance):
```

Comment: Yes I need to use and in this case, thinks that the function show is a variable